How Can I Send a FCM notification using the expo push token?
I'm using expo notification to handle my notifications. But my api it's not sending the notifications with the expo token. When I send it by the expo site it works fine. Is there any way to convert the token to a FCM or send with the expo token??
This is the token I get with
token = await Notification.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
                projectId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.eas.projectId,
            })

{"data": "ExponentPushToken[zVrYVeGa5RO_Rov5RnKh38]", "type": "expo"}
My api code looks like this
public void enviarFcm(String token, String body) {
        try {

            InputStream inputStream = ChatService.class.getResourceAsStream("/firebase.json");
            //FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("C:\\Projetos\\Rodovia\\rodoviaviam-5cf5a-firebase-adminsdk-odgju-47f821e743.json");
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)
                    .createScoped(Arrays.asList(MESSAGING_SCOPE));
            credentials.refreshIfExpired();

            String accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(
                    new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials));

            JsonObject message = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject messageContent = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject notification = new JsonObject();
            notification.addProperty("title", "Chat ViaM");
            notification.addProperty("body", body);
            messageContent.add("notification", notification);
            messageContent.addProperty("token", token);
            message.add("message", messageContent);

            HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(
                    new GenericUrl(FCM_URL),
                    ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", message.toString()));
            request.getHeaders().setAuthorization("Bearer " + accessToken);

            HttpResponse response = request.execute();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.parseAsString());
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("Error response: " + e.getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


I just discovered that the following method get the FCM Token instead of expo push token.
const token = await Notification.getDevicePushTokenAsync()

But maybe use the expo push notification api is better, because it works with fcm, apn, and can handle foreground notifications, witch FCM itself can't
